# Solve the following ODE. $(D^6+1)y=2.e^{3x}+2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following ODE.

$(D^6+1)y=2.e^{3x}+2$

My work-

$D^6+1=0$

This will solve

$r^6.(Cosx+iSinx)^6=r^6.(Cos6x+Sin6x)=-1$

This gives the solutions for $r.(Cosx+iSinx)$ as below.

$\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\ \ ,\ i\ ,\ \frac{-\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{i}{2},\ \frac{-\sqrt3}{2}-\frac{i}{2},\ \ i,\ \ \frac{\sqrt3}{2}-\frac{i}{2} $

So the solutions for the homogenous solutions would be,

$y=c_1e^{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}+c_2e^{i}+c_3e^{\frac{-\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}+c_4e^{\frac{-\sqrt3}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}+c_5e^{i}+c_6e^{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}$

Then I can find the particular solution as follows,

$y=A.e^{3x}+C$, then I can substitute to ODE and get the answer.

Is this correct? Is there any other method for higher order differential equations?
If so, please share with me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is $D^6$ a $6$th derivative operator?

Comment: Hello @js9 yes. It's the 6th derivative

Comment: what you used (method of undetermined coefficients) is the first approach I'd take. Otherwise, perhaps you can try variation of parameters approach.